# Quais as formas corretas: hambúrguer x hambúrger e burger x burguer?

Tags: vocabulário, abreviações

"A cada hora" surge uma nova "hamburgueria", e junto, vejo mais variações na escrita.

Fui pesquisar qual seria o correto entre **burger x burguer**, e acabei encontrando até a palavra **hambúrger**, e no final, fiquei com dúvida no **hambúrguer x hambúrger** e **burger x burguer**, pois não encontrei nada.

---

**Edit:**
Além das formas escritas, considerar os acentos.

---

Gostaria de saber quais as formas corretas de escrita, e dependendo o caso, qual a língua.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em inglês: *hamburger* ou *burger*; com queijo, *cheeseburger*.

Em português: *hambúrguer* ou, no coloquial, *X-burger* (coloquial baseado no inglês) ou *X-búrguer* (coloquial baseado no português).

Estou me baseando nos padrões de aportuguesamento comuns e na acentuação de palavras como líder, revólver.

Comment: Com "U" é português, sem "U" é inglês?
Com "ham" é a palavra, sem "ham" é abreviação?
Em português, sempre com acento no "U"?

Comment: Exatamente! Ou em "francês" sem-vergonha, "exatmont"!  